# Trying to find selected radio button. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can read out text field values, but when I try to find the selected radio button, I get nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {

    var title      = $('#title').attr('value');
    var owner      = $('#owner').attr('value');
    var users      = $('#users').attr('value');
    var groups     = $('#groups').attr('value');
    var begin_date = $('#begin_date').attr('value');
    var end_date   = $('#end_date').attr('value');

    // get selected radio button 
    var type = '';
    for (i=0; i<document.forms[0].type.length; i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].type[i].checked) {
        type = document.forms[0].type[i].value;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="create-new">
  <form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
  ...
  <input name="type" id="type" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel <br/>
  <input name="type" id="type" value="course"     type="radio" /> Course <br/>

  <button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>
  </form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative method to getting the selected radio button (since you are already using jQuery):

```
$('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val();
```

This solution is an example on [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

The above solution is much more succinct, and you avoid any conflicts in the future if other forms are added (i.e you can avoid the potentially hazardous `document.forms[0]`).

**Update**

I tested your original function with the following fiddle and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/nujh2/

The only change I made was adding a `var` in front of the loop variable `i`.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Do I need to make any changes in the HTML? I would expect that `type` is either "individuel" or "course", but hen I do `alert(+ type);` I get `NaN`.

Comment: Why are you adding the `+` in the alert? You only need to do `alert(type)`.

Comment: Good point =) And now your solution works as well! I have no idea what I did wrong after I applied your solution. Thanks =)

Comment: You shouldn't have two fields both named type.  When you do a submit of this data the later will overwrite the earlier.  In the case of multiple the last one will be the final value.  Also you should not duplicate id's.  An id is unique on the page. I would recommend changing the names to their values and same for the ids.

Comment: Did you end up going with the jQuery solution or the jsfiddle solution? I'm curious because I'm trying to figure out why the var made that much of a difference. You could potentially have other `i`'s listed in your javascript (without the `var`, `i` is a global variable)? Remember, try to always use var when declaring a new variable.

Comment: @Brombomb - `name` for radio buttons denotes which group the radio button is a part of. They should be the same for every radio button in a specific group. If they all had different names the buttons would be mutually exclusive (you could pick all of them). More info: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Comment: @Brombomb - I do agree that the id's should not be the same, although I don't think id's are even necessary here, so @Sandra I would get rid of the id's unless you have a need for them. If you do have a need, don't duplicate them.

Comment: @McStretch good catch.  Forgot about that, thought there was another attribute to denote grouping.